# How to store Form data in a H2 Database (currently works using POSTman, but not the website form)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, h2

I am just teaching myself the Spring framework and am trying to makie a simple library app which stores user (book) inputs in a form in the H2 Database, and then shows the user the newly inputted data from the H2 Database.

Form submission attempt [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wsul.png):

[image]

I now have a working POST method which correctly saves a new book to the H2 repository - however when I try to connect this method to the submission of a form, no such repository stores occur.

Form submission attempt [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmOHo.png):

[image]

Working POST request using POSTman [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wfZU.png):

[image]

Working POST request using POSTman [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk2Ef.png):

[image]

### Code snippets below:

HTMLfile with the Thymeleaf form inside:

```html
    <h2> Enter a book below to add it to your basket: </h2>
    <form  action="/addToBasket" th:action="@{/addToBasket}" th:object="${book}" method="post">

        <p> Book Title: <input type="text" th:field="*{bookTitle}"></p>
        <p> Author: <input type="text" th:field="*{bookAuthor}"></p>
        <p> publicationYear: <input type="text" th:field="*{publicationYear}"></p>
        <p> price: <input type="text" th:field="*{price}"></p>
        <br>
    <!--    <input type="submit" value="Submit">-->
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

POST method in the controller class which works for POST requests from POSTman, but fails to store the form data in the same way:

```
   @PostMapping("/addToBasket")
    public Basket addToBasket(@RequestBody Basket newBook) {
 
        return basketRepository.save(newBook);
    }
```

Basket @entity:

```
@Entity
public class Basket {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long basketId;
    private String bookTitle;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;

    public Basket() {
    }

    public Basket( String bookTitle, String author, String publisher) {

        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
```

Comment: Unlike your attempt with Postman, POSTing a form from your browser doesn't use JSON. https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ might help.

Comment: Thanks @AndyWilkinson I have actually been using this guide so far but I am confused as to what POSTing a form from the browser actually uses and how to grab the POSTed form's attributes and save them to the repository (as a Book). Would you know how this is achieved?

Comment: No worries Andy, I just cracked it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this is how you do it...

## Set the form up like below, (it just needs to point to the name of the path in the controller method):

```html
<form action="/addToBasket" method="post">
    B name:<input name="bookTitle" value="yosi"/><br>
    A name:<input name="author" value="lev"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

## Then set up the method in the controller like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addToBasket", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String test( Basket basket) {
        basketRepository.save(basket);
          return "Hello test : " + basket;
    }
```

^It takes in the inputs from the form as a Basket object so you just need to save this to the appropriate repository, make sure you have a toString() method in this Basket class so you can print out the results if necessary to do so

## This is my Basket class in case this is useful:

```
package springLibrary.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Basket {

   // private Set<Book> bookBasket = new HashSet<>();
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long basketId;
    private String bookTitle;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;
    public Basket() {
    }

    public Basket( String bookTitle, String author, String publisher) {

        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }


    public Long getBasketId() {
        return basketId;
    }

    public void setBasketId(Long basketId) {
        this.basketId = basketId;
    }

    public String getBookTitle() {
        return bookTitle;
    }

    public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Basket basket = (Basket) o;
        return Objects.equals(basketId, basket.basketId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Basket{" +
                "basketId=" + basketId +
                ", bookTitle='" + bookTitle + '\'' +
                ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", publisher='" + publisher + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(basketId);
    }
}
```

^it has the same variable names as those used in the HTML file.

When you run your locally hosted site, if you have an appropriate getter for basket e.g

```
@RequestMapping("/basket")
public String getBasket(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("basket", basketRepository.findAll());

    return "basket/list";
}
```

... then you should be able to see your newly stored basket object in your basket repository.